# How to inject lots of Javascript files into CHROME EXTENSION?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tinymce

I want to load lots of linked Javascript files by loading one core Javascript file.

There exist linked Javascript files.

---

Core.js

sub_1.js, sub_2.js, sub_3.js, ......, sub_n.js

---

How can I load these linked Javascript files into content script?

There are so many Javascript files. I want to load these by declaring only one core Javascript files.

I know ways to load each Javascript file.

```
[manifest.json]
....
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [....],
      "js": ["core.js", "sub_1.js", "sub_2.js"....]
    }
  ],
....
```

or

```
[background.html]
<script>
...
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "core.js" }, function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "sub_1.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "sub_2.js" }, function() {
      ....
    });
  });
});
...
```

My final objective is to inject TinyMCE into content script.

I want to solve this problem in advance.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RequireJS. http://requirejs.org/ That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [apache ant](http://ant.apache.org/), create a build script which will pack all needed js-files into one single file.

The necessary code is shipped with the tinymce developer version.
Here is some more information: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=27812.

Comment: I treid that, but not working.. tiny_mce_full.js cannot do anything